# Device screen-locking while debugging

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Screen on devices is locking automatically, but when starting debugging, it doesn't work until screen is unlocked. How to fix it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the lock time out to be after 30 minutes that way it doesnt lock whilst I am in the middle of something. Its in the settings somewhere http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ky6Z8eSgC5k

You can set UserIdleDetectionMode = Disabled in the App.xaml to prevent the lockscreen from coming down on your app while debugging/developing/testing. Dont release your app with this disabled though. See MSDN for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.useridledetectionmode(VS.92).aspx